# GetStream in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, getstream-io

I currently have a side project React Native app running everything through Firebase. I want to add a social feed. I've been able to use getstream in client mode by turning off the debugger, but after a day without the debugger I've realized that's unacceptable. So my options are:

1. Put the getstream related code in Firebase Functions:

   - `get`: This really could be on any server
   - `follow`/`unfollow` - Trigger from database update
   - `addActivity` - Trigger from database update
2. Write my own social feed code using Firebase. I hate reinventing the wheel and I think getstream would make potential future features like notification/aggregated feeds easier.

I was able to use Firebase Functions to generate the secret feed tokens. If only I could use the Chrome Debugger with getstream. It seems like I'm not in a very unique position and this should be supported.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you're having to disable the debugger? Is it because of the exception thrown in order to highlight the client shouldn't have access to app secrets?

Comment: It throws an error regarding a cors-enabled browser or something. I am in client mode so the secrets aren't there.

Comment: Please share the exact error and the version of React Native you're working with.

Comment: I've posted the error here: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/issues/108
I'm on react-native version 0.43.3